# rebuild my Android for multiple languages

Tags: android

I want to rebuild my Android application so it supports multiple languages.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'values' folder for this purpose. The default is called 'values'. For every other language you can create one like 'values-fr' 'values-en'.

Every folder contains a file called 'strings.xml' where you declare your strings in the corresponding language.
Android itself will take care of choosing the 'strings.xml' file from the correct folder.

Comment: Start from here   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html